# Sass mixin that takes a class as it's argument

Tags: sass

I'm trying to create a Sass mixin that takes a class as it's argument:

```
@mixin myMixin($el){
  > #{$el}{
    background: white;
  }
}

.myClass1{
  @include myMixin(div);
}
```

The above code works fine. I.e., elements are accepted.

But this calls an error:

```
.myClass1{
  @include myMixin(.myClass);
}
```

I've tried wrapping it in quotes and `#{}` but still no dice.

Curiously, the `*` selector also does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to quote your class:

```
.myClass1{
  @include myMixin(".myClass");
}
```